# Error - Type 'System.Web.UI.ScriptManager' does not have a public property named 'CompositeScript'

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5, sitefinity

Inside a CMS website (Sitefinity), I have a master page which contains an ASP ScriptManager control. Within the ScriptManager, I have defined a 'CompositeScripts' element which organizes all the script references related to the master page.

On rebuilding the site, I get error:

"Type 'System.Web.UI.ScriptManager' does not have a public property named 'CompositeScript'"

The following error also occurs in tandem with the above:

"Type 'System.Web.UI.ScriptManager' does not have a public property named 'CompositeScript'

I am targeting .net 3.5 from Visual Studio 2010.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sitefinity does not support .NET 3.5 and only works on versions 4.0 and above. Maybe this is why you are getting the error. Can you try to target the 4.0 version and see if it gets resolved?